# Checking Date in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm setting up a win auto job to accrue paid time off.
However, for personal time they only get a lump sum every year.
So I'm working on a pl/sql statement to check the date, but I can't get it to work.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!!!

```
IF to_char(sysdate, 'MM/dd') = '01/01' THEN
    PTO.personal_time := 8;
END IF;
```

update: to clarify. I want to check the date and if it is January first, to update the amount of personal time to 8 hours.  I'm not getting any errors, but the amount of personal time isn't changing.  There is no roll over and everyone gets one personal day, so i just set in on January 1st.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Is `table` a variable or do you expect it to change a row in a table? If it is the latter then that is not how you change data in tables; you need to use a DML statement for that.

Comment: Not only do you not know what you're doing wrong - you haven't told us what the problem is. Are you getting error messages? Is the code not setting the value? Something else? Please **edit your question** and further explain what the problem(s) are that you're encountering. You might want to read [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`TABLE` is a keyword and you cannot use it as a variable; however, if you replace `table` with the name of your variable then your code works perfectly (assuming that the variables of the appropriate names/types already exists):

```sql
DECLARE
  -- declare a type which has a field names "field"
  TYPE item_type IS RECORD(
    field NUMBER
  );

  -- declare an "item" variable
  item item_type;
BEGIN
  -- start of your code
  IF to_char(sysdate, 'MM/dd') = '04/25' THEN
    item.field := 8;
  END IF;
  -- end of your code

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( item.field );
END;
/
```

which outputs:

> ```
> 8
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=96bd41aa27b940f8df0706683aa32956)*